# How to call .exe inside asp page

Tags: asp.net

I've an asp page that: 1st. writes a txt file and 2on: I need to call a .exe file to parse the txt.

1st. point works fine, but 2on. doesn't work. I've tried to get a simple asp page that calls notepad.exe or calc.exe but didn't get it.

My code of 1st point:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
<script  runat="server">

Sub Page_Load

dim fs,f,fname,fsurname,femail,fid,fpass

fname=Request.Form("name")
fsurname=Request.Form("surname")
femail=Request.Form("email")
fid=Request.Form("id")
fpass=Request.Form("pass")

fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
f=fs.CreateTextFile("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\registre-icgc\testb.csv",true)
f.writeLine("Username;Password;FirstName;LastName;Email;Status;Privileges")
f.write(fid+";"+fpass+";"+fname+";"+fsurname+";"+femail+";"+"Active;User")
f.close
f=nothing
fs=nothing
End Sub

</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>OK</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

And my test code to 2on. point (3 options no good):

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>

<script  runat="server">
Sub Page_Load

'1st test
    Dim objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objshell.Run("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")

'2on test
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe");

'3rd test
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "if any";
process.Start();

End Sub

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>OK</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help will be apreciated.

Toni

Answer (score 1):

First of all classic asp is a server side scripting language and run inside IIS. so, it can only able to execute the .exe file in background.

Second I made some changes in the code you written which is as follows :

```
  <%
Sub Page_Load

'1st test
    Dim objShell : Set objShell = Server.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    objshell.Run("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")

End Sub

%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<% Page_Load %>
<h3>OK</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Please try to execute your own .exe file by using this. Hope the same will work fine :).

Comment: Hello @HardipsinhJadeja,

Your code returns the following error: "BC30807: 'Let' and 'Set' assignment statements are no longer supported"

Answer (score -2):

Finally I got a solution:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" Debug="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.ComponentModel" %>

<script  runat="server">

Sub Page_Load
Dim myProcess As New Process()

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\path\to\my\file.exe"
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
myProcess.Start()

End Sub

</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h3>EXECUTED</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem was the missing Imports !!

Comment: This is not classic asp it an ASP.NET

Comment: @HardipsinhJadeja I'm sorry, I'm not expert in ASP, I ve thought that it was classic Asp, not .Net